# How do I know the last time an e-mail was used

Tags: email

I have several emails on my server that is used by some people.

Some were created years ago and I suspect are not being used anymore.

Thru ftp I see the folders

```
.Drafts
.Junk
.Sent
.spam
.Trash
cur
new
tmp
```

and the files

```
dovecot-acl-list
dovecot-uidvalidity.53836d02
dovecot-uidvalidity
dovecot-keywords
subscriptions
courierimapsubscribed
courierimapacl
dovecot-quota
maildirsize
courierimapuiddb
dovecot.index.thread
dovecot.mailbox.log
dovecot.list.index
dovecot.index
dovecot-uidlist
dovecot.list.index.log
dovecot.index.log
dovecot.index.cache
```

is the `Date Modified` of any of these files a good indicator of when was an email last used? By used I mean at least read.

Comment: What do you mean by "used"? Last (dovecot) IMAP session, last email delivered to, ..., as much as easily possible from the previous.

Comment: last time the user opened the webmail system and at least read what was there.

Comment: Does your webmail system read mailboxes directly or over IMAP?

Comment: Good question. I have the traditional Horde/Squirrel Mail webmail stuff installed by hosting companies. I guess they access directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some background first: your mailboxes are in Maildir format.  Maildir mailboxes have three subdirectories, `tmp`, `new`, and `cur`.  Of these, `tmp` is used only for delivery, `new` contains new messages, and `cur` read messages.  Once delivered messages consist of immutable files in `new` and `cur`.  A message changing state from "new" to "read" essentially means moving the corresponding file from `new` to `cur`.  Various other per-message flags (`O`, `F`, etc.) are recorded with special characters appended to filenames.  IMAP folders are just Maildir subfolders `.Sent`, `.Draft`, etc. inside the inbox Maildir.

Assuming your messages live in Maildirs `/var/mail/<user>/`, this leads to the following heuristics:

```
for mb in /var/mail/*; do
    find "$mb" -type d -name cur -mtime -365 \
        -exec printf 'user %s is still active\n' $(basename "$mb") \; -quit
done
```

This mostly works, but it can produce both false positives and false negatives.  False positives because the IMAP server might troll you and update the `mtime` of `cur` folders when indexing mailboxes or while doing whatever other periodic task.  False negatives because a user might just delete the folder with the latest messages.

A much safer approach would be to parse the logs to see when was the last time your users logged in to SquirrelMail (provided that said squirrel is configured to keep such logs in the first place).

Comment: I'm fairly sure the script contains a typo, the dash in front of `cur` should be removed.